# TomEE redeploy webapp forcefully

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

In tomee i have a webapp which is deployed from the context XML file.
TomEE\conf\Catalina\localhost\test.xml
with contents:

```
<Context docBase="${APP_HOME}">
  <Loader loaderClass="com.test.WebappLoader"/>
</Context>
```

Now i have some leaks in this web app which is causing the web app redeploy to fail.
How do i force tomee to redeploy even if it has some leaks.

```
09-Feb-2021 03:18:40.006 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [test] appears to have started a thread named [DynamicRoutingUpdateWatcherThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
```